# Nginx rewrite rules, some work, some don't

Tags: nginx, rewrite

Here are the two rewrite rules:

This one works

```
rewrite ^/knowledgebase/([0-9]+)/[a-z0-9_-]+.html$ /./knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=$1 last;
```

This one doesn't

```
rewrite ^/announcements/([0-9]+)/[a-z0-9_-]+.html$ /./announcements.php?id=$1 last;
```

There is no difference between the two as far as I can see. The url to be rewritten for announcements is:

```
/announcements/2/New-Site-Design.html
```

And should be rewritten to:

```
/announcements.php?id=2
```

I really can't see how the announcements one doesn't work compared to the knowledgebase one. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

=== Added config file - my domain

```
#HTTP
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name portal2.website.co.uk website.co.uk www.website.co.uk;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/website.access_log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/website.error_log;

    root /var/www/website.co.uk/www;
    index index.php index.htm index.html;

    location ~ .php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/website.co.uk/www$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    rewrite ^/announcements$ /./announcements.php last;
    rewrite ^/announcements/([0-9]+)/[a-z0-9_-]+.html$ /./announcements.php?id=$1 last;

    rewrite ^/knowledgebase$ /./knowledgebase.php last;
    rewrite ^/knowledgebase/([0-9]+)/[a-z0-9_-]+.html$ /./knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/knowledgebase/([0-9]+)/([^/]*)$ /./knowledgebase.php?action=displaycat&catid=$1 last;

    rewrite ^/downloads$ /./downloads.php last;
    rewrite ^/downloads/([0-9]+)/([^/]*)$ /./downloads.php?action=displaycat&catid=$1 last;

}
```

In the config file above I have replaced references to my domain with 'website'

=== Edit

Here is the error log line

```
2012/06/28 11:40:04 [error] 29095#0: *7 open() "/var/www/website.co.uk/www/announcements/6/Moving-to-a-new-server.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 92.232.232.25, server: portal2.website.co.uk, request: "GET /announcements/6/Moving-to-a-new-server.html HTTP/1.1", host: "portal2.website.co.uk"
```

So the rewrite rule is just not kicking in for /announcements/id/page-title.html

Comment: Is there any other rewrites between these two? Are they in the same virtualhost or location-block? Can you post your entire configuration?

Comment: Everything in the config seems to work apart from the `announcements.php?id=$1` rewrite. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Moving-to-a-new-server` contains a captial `M`, and last I remember, rewrite rules are case-sensitive.

I'm taking a guess, but when you have been testing it with `knowledgebase` you have only supplied the latter portion in lower case.

If so, try this:

```
rewrite ^/announcements/([0-9]+)/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+.html$ /./announcements.php?id=$1 last;
```

and make a similar change for `knowledgebase`. You could just use `.*?` instead of a specific expression for the 2nd part, since you aren't actually going to use it anywhere (it would match more symbols, though).

Comment: /knowledgebase/1/General-Terms-of-Service.html
Is the url for knowledgebase so no dice :-(

Comment: Right we seem to be in business, the knowledge base one did not rely on the bit after however the announcements one. Changed and fixed.

Comment: This is the rewrite working for your knowledgebase urls:

`rewrite ^/knowledgebase/([0-9]+)/([^/]*)$ /./knowledgebase.php?action=displaycat&catid=$1 last;`

So its *not* this one that rewrites:

`rewrite ^/knowledgebase/([0-9]+)/[a-z0-9_-]+.html$ /./knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=$1 last;`

Comment: well no it is, the first one listed is for categorys where there is no .html on the end of the URL. The second one rewrites to article as the url has .html on the end ;-)

Comment: You are wrong. `([^/])*` will match "Foobar.html" which `[a-z0-9_-]+.html` won't match.

Comment: I bet that if you check, `/knowledgebase/1/General-Terms-of-Service.html` gets rewritten to `/./knowledgebase.php?action=displaycat&catid=1`

Answer (score 0):

Jay is correct in his answer about the capital `M`. The reason why the write works on knowledge base is because this is the rewrite that is matched:

`rewrite ^/knowledgebase/([0-9]+)/([^/]*)$ /./knowledgebase.php?action=displaycat&catid=$1 last;`

And not this one:

`rewrite ^/knowledgebase/([0-9]+)/[a-z0-9_-]+.html$ /./knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=$1 last;`

`[^/]` is a negative match, which means to match everything *not* matching `/`, which explains why your request to `/knowledgebase/1/General-Terms-of-Service.html` was rewritten, but not `/announcements/2/New-Site-Design.html`